# How to get the position of the current touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch

I'm building a game that basically the goal is to hold a button pressed for a long time.
The game starts with the "touchesBegan" call, and ends on "touchesEnded".

I have a issue that some very specific times this call, is not called. After a some search i figured out i'm not the only one with this problem :

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1507669?tstart=0

There is a known problem that some times "touchesEnded" is not called.
So the work around i was thinking of doing, is setting a timer, and checking every once in a while, if there is a finger pressing, and where exactly on the screen.
Problem is, i know only about these methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

And nun of them serve me for this use.

Is there a way of getting the current touch on screen?

Thanks

Comment: when touchesEnded: is not called, touchesCancelled: is called instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### touchesCancelled:withEvent:

When a touch begins, `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is called. After that, at some point in the future, either `touchesEnded:withEvent:` or `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` will be called! You can, e.g. create a method `touchesEndedOrCancelled:withEvent:` and call that method from both touchesEnded and touchesCancelled.

To get the current touches you need to keep track of them on your own. Just create a mutable set `_allTouches`

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_allTouches unionSet:touches];
    // ...
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_allTouches minusSet:touches];
    // ...
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_allTouches minusSet:touches];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, May i ask what is the difference between touch ended and touch canceled?

Comment: Touches get cancelled for example when you are touching a view and a call comes in on your iPhone. In this case `touchesCancelled:` is called. `touchesEnded:` is called when you lift the finger (but only if the touch wasn't cancelled before :D)